# Вызовы деструктора класса

Tags: c++

Почему компилятор вызывает сначала деструктор В,а потом А. Почему одного деструктора В не хватает ?
И есть разница в данных записях:

```
const A *a = new B;
const A *a = new А;
```

Вот сам код:

```
class A
{
public: 
    virtual ~A() { f(); }
public:
    virtual void f() const { std::cout << 1; }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    ~B() { f(); }
private:
    virtual void f() const { std::cout << 2; }
};

int main()
{
    const A *a = new B;
    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
21
```

Comment: Потому что деструктор вызывается рекурсивно для всех подъобъектов в порядке, обратном порядку инициализации этих подъобъектов.

Comment: есть разница в данных записях ?:

`const A *a = new B;`
`const A *a = new А;`

Comment: @ANGRYSHARKknyaz2000, для вашего случая, нет никакой разницы, а вообще теоретически, да, но на практике нет.

Comment: @ヒミコ Как это нет разницы? Даже вывод разный будет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ой, я все наоборот написал.

Comment: А почему компилятор разрешает выделять память так: `const A *a = new B;` ?
Указатель же указывает на тип А, а мы выделям для типа В.

Comment: потому что тип `B` также является типом `A`, так как наследует от него

Comment: Так, а какого типа будет указатель? Типа В или А?

Comment: Указатель будет с типом  `const A *` и будет указывать на подъобъект `A` объекта `B`

Comment: А зачем вообще такая запись нужна :`const A *a = new B;` ?

Comment: @VTT А почему вообще вызывается 2 конструктора:в суперклассе и наследнике? Я понимаю что когда мы удаляем указатель на объект, то вызывается деструктор для данного объекта. Деструктор по сути обычная функция, но мы же когда вызываем обычную функцию не вызываются же версии наследника и суперкласса.

Comment: потому что конструктор и деструктор вызываются для каждого объекта, а объект класса `B` содержит подъобъект класса `A`

Comment: Это удобно. Обычно при наследовании, при разрушении наследника разрушается и базовый класс, при этом код для разрушения членов базового класса одинаков для всех наследников. Поэтому, чтобы в наследниках не переписывать код деструктора базового класса, сделано так, чтобы деструкторы вызывали рекурсивно. Осталось только понять в каком порядке. Как было отмечено, алгоритм разрушения базового класса не зависит от того, кем он был унаследован. А алгоритм наследника может зависить от состояния базового класса. Поэтому сначала вызывается деструктор базового класса, потом наследника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый объект класса `B` содержит объект класса `A` в качестве базового подобъекта. Разумеется, для этого подобъекта будет вызываться деструктор класса `A`. Как же еще?

Деструкторы в С++ традиционно вызываются в порядке, обратном порядку конструкции. Конструкция делается в порядке от подобъектов ко всему объекту. Деструкция - в обратном порядке: сначала деструктор объекта, потом деструкторы его подобъектов.

Разница в записях `new A` и `new B`, разумеется, есть. По-моему очевидно, что в первом случае создается объект класса `A`, а во втором - класса `B`.

Comment: Если при `new B` создается  объект класса `B`, то почему я могу вызывать методы  класса `B`, через указатель `a` ?

Comment: @ANGRY SHARK knyaz2000: В этом заключается сущность *полиморфизма*. Когда вы выполняете виртуальный вызов, конкретный метод для вызова выбирается на основе анализа *динамического* типа объекта. Несмотря на то, что ваш указатель имеет тип `A *`, фактически он указывает на объект типа `B`. `B` - это и есть динамический тип объекта в данном случае. Это значит, что все виртуальные вызовы будут выполняться именно на основе типа `B`. Это фундаментальное свойство ООП.